# Makefile cannot link share library .la that wrote by C++

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries, autotools

Makefile contains .la extension file that create libclamav.

> libclamav_la_LIBADD = @LIBLTDL@  $(IFACELIBADD) $(LLVMLIBADD) 
>   libclamav_internal_utils.la @LIBCLAMAV_LIBS@ @THREAD_LIBS@ @LIBM@
>
> libclamav_la_DEPENDENCIES =  @LTDLDEPS@ $(IFACEDEP) $(LLVMDEP) 
>   libclamav_internal_utils.la
>
> libclamav_la_CFLAGS =
>   -I../my_include/src/wrapper -DSEARCH_LIBDIR=\"$(libdir)\"
>
> libclamav_la_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/lib32 -lOpenCL  @TH_SAFE@ -version-info
>   @LIBCLAMAV_VERSION@ -no-undefined

My point to link shared library to Makefile by add -L/my_shared_library_path/mylib.so to libclamav_la_LIBADD by example.

> libclamav_la_LDFLAGS = -L/my_shared_library_path/ -lmylib @TH_SAFE@ -version-info
>   @LIBCLAMAV_VERSION@ -no-undefined

Makefile cannot like member function name by through an errors.

> ../libclamav/.libs/libclamav.so: undefined reference to 'member_function_in_mylib.so'

Comment: Can you perform the link successfully on the command line (i.e. without a makefile), using those flags?

Answer (score 1):

The text quoted in your question clearly belongs in a `Makefile.am` (or `Makefile.in`) from an autoconf'd packed relying on pkg-config.  If that is text that you have in a `Makefile`, then you have many more issues to deal with.  Since `@LIBCLAMAV_LIBS@` already appears in `libclamav_la_LIBADD`, you need to configure `pkg-config` to emit the proper flags to locate your library at configure time.

It is never appropriate to put machine specific code in a `Makefile.am` (or `Makefile.in`).  Since `my_shared_libary_path` is specific to your box, the appropriate way to get the related flags into the build is via `pkg-config` or by adding to `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` during `configure`.  (Note: `-I` flags in an `autoconf` derived packed go in `CPPFLAGS` rather than `CFLAGS`)

If you did run configure, just try:

```
configure ... LDFLAGS=-L/my/shared/library/path CPPFLAGS=-I/my_include/src/wraper
```